# Can I declare a function return value if it returns multiple types?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Suppose I have a function like this:

```py
def A(test=False):
    if test:
        return 1
    return "no value passed in for test"
```

In Typescript, you can do something like

```js
function A(test=false) <number | string> {
    ...
}
```

But if I try to do same thing with Python, I get an error.

```py
def A(test=False) -> (int, str):

def A(test=False) -> [int, str]:

def A(test=False) -> int or str:
```

I understand Python better with dealing with ambiguity in type checking. So this probably is a non issue. but I am interested if there is a correct way of doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) for an "either or" relation of multiple types.

```py
from typing import Union

def fn(test=False) -> Union[str, int]:
    if test:
        return 1
    return "no value passed in for test"
```

In Python 3.10, the binary-or operator `|` can be used to create unions as per [PEP 604](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/):

```py
def fn(test=False) -> str | int:
    if test:
        return 1
    return "no value passed in for test"
```